# How to remove only one instance using Array.prototype.filter()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my React app I have a method deleteNumberFromList. This method calls a setter hook and removes a number from the array:

```
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState<number[]>([]);

const deleteNumberFromList = (num: number) => {
    setValuesList(valuesList.filter((e) => e !== num));
};
```

This works, but the problem is that when I have duplicate values in the list, it will remove all instances of this value

So when I have an array:

[2, 4, 2, 6]

and I want to remove a number 2 from the list, the result will be [4, 6] while it should be [4, 2, 6]

I guess Array.prototype.filter() is not the right way to do this?

How can I rewrite the deleteNumberFromList method, so it deletes only one instance of a number, and not all duplicates?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: use `.indexOf`...

Comment: we can resolve this issue with filter. see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example snippet, the function `removeFirstFoundval` takes the array and a number as argument and returns a new array with the first instance of the number removed.

```js
let nums = [2, 4 ,2 ,6]

let removeFirstFoundval = (arr, num) => {
    const idx = arr.indexOf(num)

    if (idx === -1) {
        return [...arr]
    }


    return arr.filter((el, i) => i !== idx)
}


console.log(removeFirstFoundval(nums, 2))
```

With proper types for your use case. The function `removeFirstFoundval` doesn't mutate the state so you can just use it in a functional update.

```
const removeFirstFoundval = (arr: number[], num: number): number[] => {
        const idx = arr.indexOf(num)

        if (idx === -1) {
            return [...arr]
        }

        return arr.filter((el, i) => i !== idx)
}

const removeNumberFromList = (num: number) => {
    setValuesList(prev => removeFirstFoundval(prev, num))
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @subashMahapatra, I implemented your solution and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
const deleteNumberFromList = (num: number) => {
    setValuesList(valuesList=> {
       valuesList.splice(valuesList.indexOf(num),1);
       return valuesList;
    });
};
```

- .indexOf(element) gives the index of first matched element.
- .splice(index, count) removes a number of an element based on count starting from index

Comment: You should avoid `splice`, as that mutates the array, leading to hard-track side effects.

Comment: Here I take an instance of the prevState, mutate it and return the mutated value which eventually replaces the value.I think Side effects shouldn't be an issue here. @torkel

Comment: In general mutation of lists and objects is something to avoid in React

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [valuesList, setValuesList] = useState<number[]>([]);

const deleteNumberFromList = (num: number) => {
    const idx = valuesList.indexOf(num)
    if (idx === -1) {
        return setValuesList(valuesList)
    }
    const newList = valuesList.slice(0, idx).concat(valuesList.slice(idx+1))
    setValuesList(newList);
};
```

`indexOf` checks if the given element is included in the list. If the element is not present, we don't need to change it. If it is present, we construct a new array such that said index is removed.

Comment: thanks @torkel, I tried your solution but I get the error: 'xs is not defined'

Comment: That was from my bad copy pasting from my terminal! Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example. Try this:**

```
let allValues = [2, 4, 2, 5];
let unique = allValues.filter( (value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index );
```